# Tic Tac Toe Referee

Tags: python, function, loops, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to solve a new task - Tic Tac Toe Referee. I have to make a judgement of the game result, but not to make an algorythm of the game. The program should return only one winner (O or X) or draw (like a string, by the way).

```
def checkio(game_result):
    for y in game_result:
        if y == "XXX":
            return "X"
        elif y == "OOO":
            return "O"
    for y in range(3):
        if game_result[y][0] == game_result[y][1] == game_result[y][2] != None:
            return game_result[y][0]
        if game_result[0][y] == game_result[1][y] == game_result[2][y] != None:
            return game_result[0][y]
    if game_result[0][0] == game_result[1][1] == game_result[2][2] != None:
        return game_result[1][1]
    if game_result[2][0] == game_result[1][1] == game_result[0][2] != None:
        return game_result[1][1]
    return "D"
```

I really don't understand where had i done a mistake and the system answers that in case of:

- .OX
- .XX
- .OO

("." means an empty cell)

My result is "." but the right result is "D".

How to fix it? Thanks for attention.

Comment: replace `None` with `'.'`

Comment: Thank you very much, you've just solved a problem in 2 minutes! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
if game_result[y][0] == game_result[y][1] == game_result[y][2] != None:
        return game_result[y][0]
```

is causing you trouble - all of the cells in column 0 are the same, you you are returning the value of column[0][0] i.e '.', when you should be returning 'draw'